# mysql how to display last 2 records for each customer

Tags: mysql

I want to display last 2 records for each customer based on date, 
eg:

```
      id   |   name   |   date
       1   |    a     |  2015-10-11
       2   |    a     |  2015-09-11
       3   |    b     |  2015-10-10
       4   |    b     |  2015-09-01
```

I tried like

> SELECT id,cust_id FROM ( SELECT id,cust_id @currcount := IF(@currvalue
>   = cust_id, @currcount + 1, 1) AS cnt    FROM customer   ORDER BY id DESC) AS whatever WHERE cnt <= 2

but it displays all records

Comment: This question has been asked and answered several times on SO.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
) sub
ORDER BY id ASC

This will select the last 2 rows from table, and then order them in ascending order.

Comment: i dont want to last row i want 2 records for each customer

Comment: You mean any two records, not necessarily last.then you can use following code.
        select * from customer LIMIT 2;

Comment: not any two records for each customer only 2 records

Comment: check it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results